# How to rotate around world coordinate, after a complex transform

Tags: opengl, opengl-compat

How to rotate an object around world axis? The object has been transformed(rotate, translate), and the matrix has been pushed.
Can I load a matrix first, and then multiply the top matrix in the opengl-stack?

I know the order of opengl operation is inverted,
for example:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity(); // E
gl.glTranslatef(1, 0, 0); // M
gl.glRotatef(60, 0, 0, 1); // N
```

The cube will rotate first and then translate.
And I know that's why: The transform is MNv, equals to M(Nv), and it matches the implemention of "opengl pipeline".

Then, I want to make the object rotate 60degree by world Z-axis(0,0,1), I can add this code before the first transform statement:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity(); // E
gl.glRotatef(45, 0, 0, 1); // this is newly added
gl.glTranslatef(1, 0, 0); // M
gl.glRotatef(60, 0, 0, 1); // N
```

But, the object has been experienced a complex transform, so I have to save the transform matrix in the stack:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity(); // E
gl.glTranslatef(1, 0, 0); // M
gl.glRotatef(60, 0, 0, 1); // N
....
gl.glPushMatrix();
```

Then I pop this matrix, and multiply the rotation matrix(which rotates around world coordinate/axis). But if I glPop, then glRotate(or glMul), the order is incorrect.

Can I load the rotation matrix first, and then multiply the top matrix in the stack?

Unfortunatly, I'm programming on android, and I there's no implemention of "glGetFolat" in GL10, so I can't see the result matrix of my complex transform. I tried to cast GL10 interface to GL11, which has method "glGetFolat", but it always return 0. I searched online, some answer is My device's OS hasn't supported GL11.

```java
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // dither is enabled by default, we don't need it
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    // clear screen in white
    gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    // load a complex transform
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -3.0f);
    gl.glMultMatrixf(mComplexMatrix, 0);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // clear screen
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // set-up modelview matrix
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(mIncrement, 0, 0, 1); // of course it's wrong
    gl.glPushMatrix();

    // draw our object
    gl.glPopMatrix();
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    mCube.draw(gl);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Getting the model view matrix is provided by the extension [`OES_matrix_get`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_matrix_get.txt)

Comment: I recommend to use a matrix library for the matrix transformations. Only load the final matrix to the current model view matrix. This would give full flexibility and makes the code portable to other hardware and OpenGL (ES) versions.